# Cucumber tags - execute ONLY features that have 2 specific tags

Tags: tags, cucumber

I want to tag feature files in a manner that tells me it is set up to run in production or development environments.

I want to be able to run features that have BOTH @SMOKE and @PROD tags that don't mean I want all features that have @SMOKE and all @PROD I want ONLY those features that have BOTH of those tags.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: @CucumberOptions(tags = "@smoke and @prod") -- https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/api/#running-a-subset-of-scenarios

Answer (score 0):

so this syntax makes no sense to me but this does work:

-Dcucumber.options='--tags @BVT --tags @PROD'